# Get a entire row based on a particular condition on adjoining column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, top-n

My table

```
integer   | party   | value | and many more columns
----------+---------+-------+----------------------
 1        | abc     |  40   | -----
 1        | abc     |  90   | -----
 2        | pqr     |  12   | -----
 1        | abc     | 120   | -------
 2        | pqr     |  86   | --------
```

and so on

I want **entire row** to be retrieved which has max value

Sample output for above table

```
1    abc    120
2    pqr     86
```

For a particular distinct party I want row to be picked up which has maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rank` window function to find the "max" row per party:

```
SELECT 
    id, party, value
FROM
    (SELECT 
         id, party, value, 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY party ORDER BY value DESC) AS rk
     FROM   
         mytable) t
WHERE  
    rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use simple aggregation  function  MAX(), assume integer is a id column

```
select id,party, max(value) as max_val from your_table
group by id,party
```

Comment: Mentioning a user that hasn't participated in the comments won't mention them. 